# JavaScript ES6 Code highlighting

Tags: highlighting, minted, sourcecode

I'm using the latest minted to highlight my sourcecode.
I've got a lot of code listings using ES5 and ES6 javascript features but minted is lacking a lot of them still.

What can I do to get proper ES6 code highlighting?

Comment: `minted` uses Pygments to do the actual highlighting. So you could create a [custom Pygments lexer](http://pygments.org/docs/lexerdevelopment/), perhaps based on the existing JavaScript lexer. An ES6 lexer [has been requested](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/issues/1100/add-support-for-ecmascript-6), but it doesn't look like any work on implementation has been done yet.

Answer (score 1):

This is an attempt to create a javaScript listing for ES6, Node.js, Express.js, Jasmine keywords. I will include more key words from popular JavaScript frameworks as time allows.

into: https://github.com/xgirma/latex-javaScript

A sample express listing is below: 
[image]

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  You should include more information than just a link.  Explain what coding you have made and how it solves the problem.

Comment: What about https://github.com/ghammock/LaTeX_Listings_JavaScript_ES6?